# ItemUpdated fires when no item is added

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

I have an ItemUpdated event receiver in a document library in SharePoint 2010.

When I try to upload a document with a name that already exists in my library I get an error message "The specified name is already in use". That is fine.

But the ItemUpdated event is fired anyway and I don't want my code to run if no document was added. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it is possible, however you will have to make changes to your event receiver,

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  if (CheckIfDocumentAlreadyExists(properties.Item.File.Name))
  {
    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "Some error has occured....";
  }
}
```

and then create a method named as CheckIFDocumentAlreadyExits and put code where it will check if file exists or not,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359672/how-to-determine-if-a-file-exists-in-a-sharepoint-spfolder

Answer (score 0):

My method:

```
private bool CheckIfDocumentAlreadyExists(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    bool documentExists = false;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.AfterUrl))
    {
        var existingDocument = properties.Web.GetFile(properties.AfterUrl);
        documentExists = existingDocument.Exists;
    }
    return documentExists;
}
```